# iOS Photos library - how to get the REAL filename?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

I am looking for either a Swift or Objective C solution for this. Here, I am showing my example using swift.

I am using the Photos framework on iOS and having a hard time finding the REAL filename instead of the `IMG_4227.JPG` type. The name of my image is actually `myawesomefilename.jpg` and I see this file name if I airdrop or transfer to dropbox the image from my iPhone. But when I use the Photos framework, I get the names as `IMG_4227.JPG`.

There is an app on the app store which is able to get the real file names of all images, so it is definitely possible. I just don't know how.

Here's how I am currently getting the `IMG_4227.JPG` type names:

```
func exifTapped(asset: PHAsset) {
        print("name: \(asset.value(forKey: "filename"))")

        getURL(ofPhotoWith: asset) { (url) in
            print("URL: \(url)")
            let data = NSData.init(contentsOf: url!)!
            if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data, nil) {
                let imageProperties2 = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil)! as NSDictionary
                print("imageProperties2: ", imageProperties2)
            }
        }
    }


    func getURL(ofPhotoWith mPhasset: PHAsset, completionHandler : @escaping ((_ responseURL : URL?) -> Void)) {

        if mPhasset.mediaType == .image {
            let options: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
            options.canHandleAdjustmentData = {(adjustmeta: PHAdjustmentData) -> Bool in
                return true
            }
            mPhasset.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
                completionHandler(contentEditingInput!.fullSizeImageURL)
            })
        } else if mPhasset.mediaType == .video {
            let options: PHVideoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
            options.version = .original
            options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
            PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: mPhasset, options: options, resultHandler: { (asset, audioMix, info) in
                if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                    let localVideoUrl = urlAsset.url
                    completionHandler(localVideoUrl)
                } else {
                    completionHandler(nil)
                }
            })
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:** None of the duplicate solutions are any different than what I already have and they all give the `IMG_4227.JPG` type names instead of the real name. So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: None of the duplicate solutions are any different than what I already have and they all give the IMG_4227.JPG type names instead of the real name. So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @matt None of the duplicate solutions are any different than what I already have and they all give the IMG_4227.JPG type names instead of the real name. So this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
let resources = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: asset)
print("Filename: \((resources.first as! PHAssetResource).originalFilename)")
```